# How to display recent searches in the Google Search app?

Tags: google, search-history

When other people use the Google Search box on their Android device, about 3 items from the recent search history will show under the textbox. However, when I open the search box with my Google ID, nothing shows up.

I googled for this, and it seems all I can find are ways to *disable* recent searches. None of them solved my problem to *enable* recent searches. A couple that were somewhat relevant were all for older versions of the Google app. I am using the newest version, and everything concerning search history and privacy were turned on in my device.

So, how to display recent searches in the Google Search app?

Comment: Have you confirmed it on **Google (app) - Settings - Accounts & privacy - Google Account History - Web & App Activity - tick the 'Include history...' checkbox**?

Comment: I can see connectivity potentially being a factor as well - if you're on a slow internet connection (or not connected at all) it might be unable to fetch your search history in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yes, "Include history from chrome and other apps in your web and app activity" and "store app activity from this deice for my account" are both checked.